# How to share artifact between workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

I am new to GitHub and wanted to know how to share artifact between two workflows if not using third party actions (because they are restricted in our company).
I have one workflow that builds backend image and puts it into JFrog artifactory. The branch name and the build number are represented as "tag", e.g. master-1, master-2, etc.
After build is complete and docker image pushed to artifactory (with name master-1) and the build workflow produces the .txt file with JFrog URL and tag so k8s can pull image from the Jfrog:

`echo ${docker_image_name_with_tag} > docker_image_name_backend.txt`

The content of the file is something like that:

`repositoryX.jfrog.company.io/appnameX:master-1`

In one workflow with build job and deploy job it works perfectly: build job produces that .txt file and uploads in into github as artifact, then deploy job downloads it and content is passed to `kubectl apply -f` command..

But our company wants to move forward with reusable workflows..
So we need one build workflow that produces this .txt file and then deploy workflow (reusable) which gets contents of that file and deploys an image to k8s.

How it could be solved? Mby this .txt file is not needed at all, but how to share the JFrog URL and tag with deploy workflow?

Comment: First thing on top of my mind: upload/download that file in a JFrog raw repository (or any other object storage), used as a staging area

Comment: yes. it will definitely work but when I make every day the same .txt file (when building my stuff) or let it be numerated (incremened by 1, e.g. docker_image_name_backend_1.txt), docker_image_name_backend_2.txt) how I should tell to the deployment to use particular file, not the latest one?

Comment: You can try a naming convention using the workflow name-id. So, the build workflow save the file `build-X.txt`. The deploy job triggered will download the file `build-X.txt`. Otherwise, if the deploy job is triggered manually, the source build will be an input

Comment: if we talking about build and deploy jobs it's not a problem. but what we want is to make 2 separate workflows: build and deploy. And Deploy needs somehow know what number to use.